# COALESCE and str_replace

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm using COALESCE to only update not empty input from a form to my sql DB and everything works fine :

```
$horiz_deux = $_POST["horiz_deux"];
$horiz_gauche = $_POST["horiz_gauche"];
other ones ...

mysql_query("UPDATE inscription SET horiz_deux = COALESCE('$horiz_deux', horiz_deux) WHERE id = $dossard");
mysql_query("UPDATE inscription SET horiz_gauche = COALESCE('$horiz_gauche', horiz_gauche) WHERE id = $dossard");
other updates...
```

But when i'm trying to get . replace by , with

```
$horiz_deux = str_replace(".", ",",$_POST["horiz_deux"]);
```

it update all the other input as well.

Any idea for this ?

Comment: what do you mean by "other input as well"? it should only update where the id is "$dossard"?

Comment: i got other $xxx = $_POST["xxx"];

Comment: the current source-code shows that all inputs are updated by UPDATE-Statements at all times. There is no condition which would provide only for the horiz_deux to be updated alone.

Comment: Well in DB they wont be updated if there was no value in the input from the form. I tested it and work fine. The only thing, is im trying to replace . for , but it update all column in bd even if it was empty in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php always returning a string or an array. So the value of $horiz_gauche will always be something diffrent from NULL and therefore be selected by the COALESCE-statement causing an update to horiz_gauche in the database.

You could try and print out the value of $horiz_gauche just before you insert it into the SQL-Statement to confirm its contents.

You could try:

```
$horiz_deux = isset($_POST["horiz_deux"]) ? $_POST["horiz_deux"] : '';
if ($horiz_deux != '')
{
  $horiz_deux = str_replace(".", ",",$horiz_deux);
  mysql_query("UPDATE inscription SET horiz_deux = COALESCE('$horiz_deux', horiz_deux) WHERE id = $dossard");
}
```

This is quite cumbersome, you could write a loop that iterates over all the input-fields and checks them for valid input:

```
$myFieldNames = array('horiz_deux','horiz_hauche','something_else');
foreach ($myFieldNames as $fieldName)
{
  $value = isset($_POST[$fieldName]) ? $_POST[$fieldName] : '';
  $value = str_replace(".", ",",$value);
  mysql_query("UPDATE inscription SET $fieldName = COALESCE('$value', $fieldName) WHERE id = $dossard");
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly the problem... Now im trying to find a way to make it work -_-

Comment: @AntoineSt-Pierre: if you feel that the code in the answer can be improved, it is much better to add a comment to that effect. It may be in your scenario that checking for an empty string first is desirable (though, why...the code should work the same without the check), but that doesn't mean the answer is incorrect without that detail. You should leave it to the answer's author to make that change if they want it.